# Customizing the PHP exit function message

Tags: php, css

I am trying to customize the message page displayed by the PHP `exit` function to look more presentable to the user.

Currently, it shows nothing but a blank, white page.

How can I customize it to add a custom message, a "back to the previous page" link, a search form, and/or anything else I want?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent visitors and customers from seeing a blank page with an error message while validating a form, or requesting a non-existing page, you can customize and add some style to the PHP `exit` function.

Here's an example of validating a Google ReCaptcha:

```
if(!$recaptcha) {
  exit ("Please check the captcha.");
 }
```

**The above code will echo a blank page with a pre-defined error message:**

> [image: empty white page]

**Not good for business! So, let us customize that exit page:**

```
if (!$recaptcha) {
echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Contact Us</title>
<body class='container'>
<p><a href='www.websiteurl.com'><img src='imgurl' /></a>
<br><br><b><span class='yellow'>Error:</span> Please verify your're a human being
<br>by checking and verifying the Captcha.</b>
<br><span class='button' onClick='history.go(-1)'>&laquo; Back To Contact Form</span></p>
</body>
</html>";
die();
}
```

**Which will look like this:**

[image]

**Note:** To allow visitors to return to the previous page you can use this code:

```
onClick='history.go(-1)'
```

You can append it to `<span>`, `<a>`, `div>`, `<p>`, `<strong>` or whatever you want, just don't forget to give that tag a pointer class as follow: `cursor: pointer`.

Comment: `header('location: your_site'); exit();` in php no need click, `windows.location.reload();` in javascript, I wonder how you searh ?